# Get files path from text tree in python

Tags: python, directory, path

I have the following text tree, and I want to get all the possible paths.

```
 subdirectory 1
   file11
   file12
   sub-sub-directory 1
     file111
     file112
 subdirectory 2
   file 21
   sub-sub-directory 21
   sub-sub-directory 22    
     sub-sub-sub-directory 221
       file 2211
```

I expect to receive a console output with all correct possible paths, ex:

```
Ex1: Subdirectory 1/Sub-sub-directory 11/file111

Ex2: Subdirectory 1/file12

Ex3: Subdirectory 2/sub-sub-directory 22/sub-sub-sub-directory 221/file 2211
```

for any combination. Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: how is your text tree saved? is it a dict? a string?

Comment: it's saved as a string

Comment: Your example is pretty unwieldy: Sometimes a `:` at the end of a subdirectory, sometimes not. Indentation seems inconsistent (is it with tabs or normal whitespace). Is that acutually the case?

Comment: I edited the post with the correct example, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run the following for your example file (named `file.txt` here)

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

re_indent = re.compile(r"^\s*")
def key_func(line):
    return len(re_indent.match(line)[0])

with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    for key, parts in groupby(file, key=key_func):
        print(f"{key}:", [part.strip() for part in parts])
```

I get essentially (apart from formatting):

```
  indent  parts
--------  -----------------------------------------------------------
       1  ['subdirectory 1']
       3  ['file11', 'file12', 'sub-sub-directory 1']
       5  ['file111', 'file112']
       1  ['subdirectory 2']
       3  ['file 21', 'sub-sub-directory 21', 'sub-sub-directory 22']
       5  ['sub-sub-sub-directory 221']
       7  ['file 2211']
```

So, as long as the file sticks to this indentation rule, you could try the following:

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

re_indent = re.compile(r"^\s*")
def key_func(line):
    return len(re_indent.match(line)[0])

last_key = -1
paths = []
current, current_str = [], ""
with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    for key, parts in groupby(file, key=key_func):
        if key < last_key:
            current = current[:(key - 1) // 2]
            current_str = "/".join(current)
        for part in parts:
            paths.append(f"{current_str}/{part.strip()}".lstrip("/"))
        current.append(part.strip())
        current_str = paths[-1]
        last_key = key
```

to get

```
paths = [
 'subdirectory 1',
 'subdirectory 1/file11',
 'subdirectory 1/file12',
 'subdirectory 1/sub-sub-directory 1',
 'subdirectory 1/sub-sub-directory 1/file111',
 'subdirectory 1/sub-sub-directory 1/file112',
 'subdirectory 2',
 'subdirectory 2/file 21',
 'subdirectory 2/sub-sub-directory 21',
 'subdirectory 2/sub-sub-directory 22',
 'subdirectory 2/sub-sub-directory 22/sub-sub-sub-directory 221',
 'subdirectory 2/sub-sub-directory 22/sub-sub-sub-directory 221/file 2211'
]
```

which seems to be what you are looking for?